# geom_net does not plot all nodes of the network

Tags: r, networking, ggplot2, nodes

I have a df with 3 variables, "from"-"to"-"frequency".
The "from" has 5 levels and the "to" 22. "Frequency" represents how many times the connection from-to occur in my original DF.

When I plot a network with this info though, the plot shows only the 5 nodes from the "from" with arrows pointing to empty spaces.

Why I cannot plot all the nodes including also "to" nodes?
Here is the script of the `ggplot`:

```
ggplot(data=NetY, aes(from_id = from, to_id = to, linewidth =freq)) +
  geom_net(labelon=TRUE, directed = TRUE, col = "darkred",vjust=-1, arrowsize = 1, 
           selfloops = TRUE, size = 15,arrowgap = 0.05,ecolour = "grey40", repel = TRUE, 
           labelgeom = "text", labelcolour = "black") + theme_net()

head(NetY)
               from                      to Freq
1     Huishoudelijke hulp Ambulante Ondersteuning  481
2              Rolstoelen Ambulante Ondersteuning   24
3           Scootmobielen Ambulante Ondersteuning   41
4 Woonruimte aanpassingen Ambulante Ondersteuning   51
5     Huishoudelijke hulp            Dagbesteding  420
6              Rolstoelen            Dagbesteding   47
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Is it compulsory `geo_net` or you can think to use also other functions/packages?